# Removing bootstrap free spaces

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

when using bootstrap framework there is a 12 column layout in a row .

### the code is

```
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
       ...
     </div>
  </div>
```

when i am using 12 column in a row then next col will be shifted to next row

but the problem is when i am using an image on different sizes there remains some space between the images

[See the screenshot here](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/164542/a8235719d5736ae2750a6f0091b3dad4)

Comment: What is your desired result? What should be done with that space? You should understand that bootstrap columns are floated, so your layout is exactly what I would expect...

Comment: It will be too much work to do with bootstrap alone, may I suggest something else for such purpose?

Comment: @jonSurrell is correct.

Comment: You can't achieve this with bootstrap i think,but you can try http://masonry.desandro.com/#initialize-in-html

Comment: @Shijin, exactly what I was going to suggest. Other alternatives include: [SALVATTORE](http://salvattore.com/), [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/)

Comment: @Ashesh Thanks for introducing salvattore

Comment: thanks but you should see the attached screenshot.My cols are different. Also i have fixed my height with css.. but if i use a tall image on a first row ,on the next row all images go under the tall images creating a gap up.I want to fill the gaps

Comment: We have seen the screenshot, which by the way should go within your question itself and not an external site..

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because your images are varying height. Use a jQuery plugin like masonry or isotope, or try CSS3 column width...

```
.row {
 -moz-column-width: 25em;
 -webkit-column-width: 25em;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-gap:10px; 

}

.row > .col-md-4 {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 100%; 
 float:none;
}
```

http://bootply.com/g5AILTFq7h

Comment: thanks but you should see the attached screenshot.My cols are different.
Also i have fixed my height with css.. but if i use a tall image on a first row ,on the next row all images go under the tall images creating a gap up.I want to fill the gaps

Comment: Yeah, I provided an example. You'd have to tweak it to get what you want. Bootstrap alone won't work for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're issue is primarily how floats naturally work. If a containing element doesn't have enough room for all the floated elements it contains, the first floated element will drop down just below the element that proceeds it and slide to the left. If along the way of siding to the left the floated element that has dropped down encounters an element taller than the one that proceeded it, it will stop there. This will happen if the element is 1px or 100px taller.

You will either need to manually specify the position of each image, use ¿`flexbox`? or use a bit of JavaScript like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Trying to using rows and columns the way you are with Bootstrap will create gaps you are having issues with. What you want to achieve takes more than the Bootstrap grid.

I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sqw6wyp/) demo to demonstrate how floating works and what to expect when the parent container cannot contain all it's floated children. Just re-size and watch how the blocks re-arrange.

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="lg"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="sm"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

```css
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: green;
}
.sm {
    height: 35px;
}
.lg {
    height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: yes got it :D . But cant i solve this problem without using masonry??

Comment: I did mention flexbox, have you looked into that? Here's an example: http://demosthenes.info/blog/844/Easy-Masonry-Layout-With-Flexbox. Though you will be limited to the browsers that support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex. You could also look into using CSS columns: http://demosthenes.info/blog/825/Pinterest-Style-Column-Layout-In-Pure-CSS.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is the `<div class="row">` spans the entire width of the container and it holds the columns.  That columns where you are seeing a blank space actually fill that space so everything is really acting as it should.  It's just that your image doesn't fill the entire space.  You can try setting that image's height to 100%. either through css

```
img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

or inline like `<img style="height:100%;">`

Comment: It would mess with the aspect ratios.

Comment: If you just adjust the height the width will scale properly.  I mean you can add `width: auto;`

Comment: `height: 100%` only works if the parent element has a height declared on it.

Comment: @hungerstar good catch.  It's tough to work on this with only a screenshot, it'd be nice to have code in a fiddle or something to inspect

Comment: @MichaelHamilton for sure. I've attempted enough percentage height's that I now have it burned into my brown how it works!